# Array inside list

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I'm really confused trying to solve this problem. I'm trying to use the sklearn function: `MinMaxScaler` but I'm getting an error because it seems to be that I'm setting an array element with a sequence.

The code is:

```
    raw_values = series.values
    # transform data to be stationary
    diff_series = difference(raw_values, 1); 
    diff_values = diff_series.values; 
    diff_values = diff_values.reshape(len(diff_values), 1) 

    # rescale values to 0,1
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    scaled_values = scaler.fit_transform(diff_values); print(scaled_values)
    scaled_values = scaled_values.reshape(len(scaled_values), 1)
```

"series" is a differenced time series that I'm trying to rescale between [0,1] with `MinMaxScaler` and the Time series was previously differenced in pandas.

I get the following error when running the code:
`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Which I don't understand is the fact that if there is just one `feature` or variable in one column, the code runs all right, but in this case **I have 2 `features`, each one in a different column.**

Traceback:

```
File "C:/....py", line 88, in prepare_data
    scaled_values = scaler.fit_transform(diff_values); print(scaled_values)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 494, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 292, in fit
    return self.partial_fit(X, y)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 318, in partial_fit
    estimator=self, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 382, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

And this is what I obtain if I print `diff_values`

```
[[array([  -1.3,  119. ])]
 [array([ 0.5, -9. ])]
 [array([  0.8,  17. ])]
 ..., 
 [array([   2.8,  742. ])]
 [array([  1.50000000e+00,  -1.65900000e+03])]
 [array([  -2.,  856.])]]
```

The full code is not mine, it's been obtained from [here](http://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-step-time-series-forecasting-long-short-term-memory-networks-python/)

**EDIT:**

[Here](https://mega.nz/#!XI1ixboS!u-K7vu18370L_6SG-c8f25iPRDnoLJZ57K9m_RDVqKc) is my dataset

Just switch the name 'shampoo-sales.csv'to 'datos2.csv' and this sentence:

```
return datetime.strptime('190'+x, '%Y-%m')
```

to this one:

```
return datetime.strptime(''+x, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: could you include the full traceback and/or give an example assignment for `series` (so we could reproduce the error)

Comment: Of course, and I'm also going to include the full code in the post

Comment: Can you post your data also (or some part of it), so that we can reproduce the error.

Comment: I forgot it. This is the link for the dataset: https://mega.nz/#!XI1ixboS!u-K7vu18370L_6SG-c8f25iPRDnoLJZ57K9m_RDVqKc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the tutorial you linked to, the object `series` is actually a Pandas `Series`.  It's a vector of information, with a named index.  Your dataset, however, contains two fields of information, in addition to the time series index, which makes it a `DataFrame`. This is the reason why the tutorial code breaks with your data.

Here's a sample from your data:

```
import pandas as pd

def parser(x):
    return datetime.strptime(''+x, '%Y-%m-%d')

df = pd.read_csv("datos2.csv", header=None, parse_dates=[0], 
                 index_col=0, squeeze=True, date_parser=parser)
df.head()
               1     2
0                     
2012-01-01  10.9  3736
2012-01-02  10.3  3570
2012-01-03   9.0  3689
2012-01-04   9.5  3680
2012-01-05  10.3  3697
```

And the equivalent section from the tutorial:
*"Running the example loads the dataset as a Pandas Series and prints the first 5 rows."*

```
Month
1901-01-01    266.0
1901-02-01    145.9
1901-03-01    183.1
1901-04-01    119.3
1901-05-01    180.3
Name: Sales, dtype: float64
```

To verify this, select one of your fields and store it as `series`, and then try running the `MinMaxScaler`.  You'll see that it runs without error:

```
series = df[1]
# ... compute difference and do scaling ...
print(scaled_values)
[[ 0.58653846]
 [ 0.55288462]
 [ 0.63942308]
 ..., 
 [ 0.75      ]
 [ 0.6875    ]
 [ 0.51923077]]
```

Note: One other minor difference in your dataset compared to the tutorial data is that there's no header in your data. Set `header=None` to avoid assigning your first row of data as column headers.

**UPDATE**
To pass your entire dataset to `MinMaxScaler`, just run `difference()` on both columns and pass in the transformed vectors for scaling.  `MinMaxScaler` accepts an n-dimensional `DataFrame` object:

```
ncol = 2
diff_df = pd.concat([difference(df[i], 1) for i in range(1,ncol+1)], axis=1)
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaled_values = scaler.fit_transform(diff_df)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works as you said but, I'm trying to use both variables to make a prediction. By doing this, it isn't possible to consider all the variables. series = df[1] is only considering the first column. Is it possible to use all the variables?

Comment: I've updated my answer to demonstrate how to scale multiple vectors at once.

Comment: This is just what I needed. Thank you.