# Why does scaling then transforming my train data cause "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence"?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series

I have a CSV dataset with hourly time series information. I'm trying to create a model for forecasting using Long Short-Term Memory (LSTM) machine learning.

I'm trying to scale train data using Sklearn's MinMax Scaler, then later, to transform the scale of the data using scale(). When tried, this returns: "*ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence*" and cites those two steps as part of the problem.

Any ideas on how to solve this error in an LSTM problem?

EDIT: looking elsewhere suggests the solution may involve uneven length of sequence inputs, but I'm still not clear how to fix that.

Here is the code cited in the error (note 113 and 42).

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

39 # scale train and test data to [-1, 1]  
40 def scale(train, test):
41    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
42    scaler = scaler.fit(train)

...

112 # transform the scale of the data
113 scaler, train_scaled, test_scaled = scale(train, test)
```

I've omitted several intermediate steps which I don't think are crucial, but perhaps I'm wrong. The error looks like this:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 113, in <module>
   scaler, train_scaled, test_scaled = scale(train, test)
  File "code.py", line 42, in scale
   scaler = scaler.fit(train)
  File "C:\...\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 325, in fit
   return self.partial_fit(X, y)
  File "C:\...\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 353, in partial_fit
   force_all_finite="allow-nan")
  File "C:\...\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 496, in check_array
   array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)
  File "C:\...\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
   return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

By best guess on why the code works for the guide template and not my code is that the guide I'm working from is only two columns (date and a number)...

```
"Month","Sales"
"1-01",266.0
"1-02",145.9
"1-03",183.1
"1-04",119.3
```

while my CSV has four columns (timestamp and three numbers):

```
timeStamp              demand   precip  temp
2012-01-01  00:00:00    4937.5  0       46.13
2012-01-01  01:00:00    4752.1  0       45.89
2012-01-01  02:00:00    4542.6  0.01    45.04
2012-01-01  03:00:00    4357.7  0       45.03
```

But ultimately, I'm new to ML and lost.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44076195/array-inside-list/44088917#44088917) might help.

Comment: the answer in Hapalop's comment solves your problem.